# How to write a regex that allows a comment at the end of line without turning off font-lock for the line in an Emacs major mode

Tags: regex, emacs, comments, font-lock

I'm trying to write a regex for a font-lock command. I want the font-lock to apply to all characters following '!', until the end of line or a comment, starting with '#', but the font-lock is turned off for the whole line after I enter any characters following '#'.

Currently I have this:

```
("!.*[^#+?]" . font-lock-custom-face)

! this works as expected #
! but here the font-lock # breaks
```

In the latter example, the comment is colored, but the line before it is not.

This works fine for a line without a comment, but the font-lock only 'ignores' the '#' sign, not the characters following it. How could I make the comment longer than just the '#' character, without breaking the font-lock on the part of the line preceding the comment?

Comment: Are `!...` lines comments as well (similar to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/47276)?

Comment: Yes, sorry about the other post (its mine...). I accidentally posted the question as guest. But no, I think they should not be comments. I just want the lines starting with `!` to be different color. I want to be able to comment the lines out with `C-x M-;`.